# Top nav bar with only CTA's?

Tags: navigation, information-architecture, cta, footers

I've tried Googling, but didn't find anything concrete.

What are your thoughts about the top nav bar of a volunteering platform containing only a sign in and sign up CTA and no other navigation links? All the other links for example: About us, Contact, How it works, etc. will go in the footer.

Answer (score 1):

I have no direct answer, but some of my immediate thoughts:

If you only have sign in & sign up CTA, why even have a nav bar at all? You can just have the buttons floating and save the entire length of the space.

Top nav bars are an established pattern. Most people know how to look for links in the nav bar. Was there a reason you broke the convention in the first place?

Have you tried A/B testing it?

Comment: Good point about not having it at all, although it is expected to have a sign-in link at the top at least? The reason given was to focus on providing the most important info on the page and get people to sign up, without them wandering off into other pages. This is a redesign that just kicked off. We plan to user test it, but I don't think we have the scope for A/B testing at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

Why would a user signup or login before they can learn about the platform. The user will have to scroll all the way to the bottom to get that information. It does not seem ideal.